# Payment Intent value is null Stripe Django

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments

I successfully created a checkout session, but when I checked the payment_intent value, it was coming out as null. Here's the code I used:

```
@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request,id):
    request_data = json.loads(request.body)
    order = Order.objects.filter(id = id).last()

    stripe.api_key = PaymentConfig.objects.all().last().stripe_secret_key
    checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        # Customer Email is optional,
        # It is not safe to accept email directly from the client side
        customer_email=request_data['email'],
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[
            {
                'price_data': {
                    'currency': str(order.amount_type.lower()),
                    'product_data': {
                        'name': order.plan.title,
                    },
                    'unit_amount': int(order.amount * 100),
                },
                'quantity': 1,
            }
        ],
        mode='payment',
        success_url=request.build_absolute_uri(
            reverse('paymentsuccess')
        ) + "?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}",
        cancel_url=request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('paymentfailed')),
    )

    order.stripe_payment_intent = checkout_session['payment_intent']
    print(payment_intent) -- **null value**
    order.save()
    return JsonResponse({'sessionId':checkout_session.id})
```

It's essential to get this value and save it in the order object so that I can access the order in the handler view after payment. Here's the handler view's code:

```
class PaymentSuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "v3/payment-successful.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        session_id = request.GET.get('session_id')

        if session_id is None:
            return HttpResponseNotFound()

        stripe.api_key = PaymentConfig.objects.all().last().stripe_secret_key
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.retrieve(session_id)
        order = get_object_or_404(Order, stripe_payment_intent=session.payment_intent) --**HERE**
        call=AfterPaymentBackend(request, order.id)
        ctx = {
            'order':order,
            'siteInfo':Company.objects.all().last()
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)
```

Is there something I'm overlooking? Thanks.

I tried asking chat GPT for the help but AI isn't that much powerful. I tried searching on google but couldn't find anything. I tried it after deploying but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using API version [2022-08-01](https://stripe.com/docs/upgrades#2022-08-01) or later, a PaymentIntent will only be created when the Session is confirmed.

You can save the corresponding PaymentIntent by listening for the `checkout.session.completed` event or by subsequently retrieving the Checkout Session using the `session_id` query param in the `success_url`.

I would recommend to go through this guide : https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders

Comment: Ultimate! Very Much Thanks!